# The fastest way to check if two lists contain the same object

Tags: java, multithreading, list, performance, comparison

I've been dealing with a problem lately where i have to wait for hours to get the right answer. 
The problem is this: 
I have two different lists that have thousands of elements.
I want to check if both lists contain the same element and if soo i want to add that element in a separate list. 
When i try with a small amount of elements in the lists, the program works perfectly fine but when i try with more elements, i have to wait for hours to get the right answer.

```
        List<Point> res1 = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Point value : w1) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1");
            Point a = value;
            for (Point point : w2) {
                if (a.equals(point)) {
                    System.out.println(Math.abs(a.x) + Math.abs(a.y));
                    res1.add(a);
                }

            }
        }
```

What is the fastest way to do this kind of comparing?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: You can test the different approaches to see which one does better.

Comment: This works only with small amounts of elements. Thanks. The problem is that this also takes to much time to find the same element.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question will surely help. Checking if something is present in a list has complexity `O(n)`, the same operation for sets is `O(1)`. And please forget `LinkedList`, it's hardly ever the right choice.

Comment: I don't see an accepted answer there and the most upvoted answer would not give a good performance here since - as you pointed out here a `LinkedList` is used and not a HashSet. Performance wise the only acceptable answer from the thread would be the apache commons answer. And performance was not a question there - but is here. So I don't think this is purely a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use HashSet you get a very efficient contains method free of charge:

```
        HashSet hsw1 = new HashSet(w1); // turn first into a hashset
        List<Point> res1 = new LinkedList<>(w2); // load the second into new list
        res1.retainall(hsw1); // retain only values that are in the first as well
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked perfectly. It has  accelerated my program thousands of time faster

Comment: if your can use a `HashSet` for w1 to begin with then you could get rid of the first conversion and be a bit faster there - but possibly pay for it by insert performance. Not sure what would outweigh the other for your case.